# Dynamically output data issue in my react-redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a test assignment for a job.
My job is to create a crypto currency application that should show the selected currency.
I have a problem when I want to show data for the selected currency, my data "currency.price" is not what I've chosen.
I apologize for my bad English

---

This is my Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect } from 'react-redux';
import {fetchCurrency} from "../actions/fetchCurrencies";
import '../App.css';
 class Settings extends Component {
  constructor(){
  super();
  this.handleCurrency = this.handleCurrency.bind(this)
 }
 handleCurrency(e) {
  this.props.fetchCurrency(e.target.name, e.target.value);
 }
 render(){
  return(
  <div className='App container'>
  <select className="custom-select"
  onChange={this.handleCurrency}>
  <option value='selected'>SELECT CURRENCY</option>
  <option value='EUR'>EUR</option>
  <option value='AUD'>AUD</option>
  <option value='GBP'>GBP</option>
  <option value='CAD'>CAD</option>
  <option value='JPY'>JPY</option>
  </select>
  <table className="table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">Rank</th>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
    <th scope="col">Price</th>
    <th scope="col">1 hour change</th>
    <th scope="col">24 hour change</th>
    <th scope="col">7 days change</th>
    <th><Link scope="col" to='/'>Home</Link></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>{this.props.currencies.map((currency,value) => {
    return (
    <tr key={currency.id}>
    <td>{currency.rank}</td>
    <td>{currency.name}</td>
    <td>{currency.symbol}</td>
    <td>{currency[`price_${value}`]}</td>
    <td>{currency.percent_change_1h}</td>
    <td>{currency.percent_change_24h}</td>
    <td>{currency.percent_change_7d}</td>
    </tr>
    )
    })}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
      )
     }
  }
 function mapStateToProps(state){
 console.log(state)
 return {
 currencies : state.currencies
 }
}
export default connect (mapStateToProps,{fetchCurrency})(Settings);
```

### This is my Action

```
const CURRENCY = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'
export const  fetchCurrency = (name, value) => dispatch => {
fetch (`${CURRENCY}${name}/?convert=${value}`)
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then (currency => dispatch ({
  type: 'FETCH_CURRENCY',
  payload: currency
 }))
 }
```

### This my Reducer

```
export default function (state=[],action){
 switch(action.type){
 case 'FETCH_CURRENCY':
 return action.payload
 default:
 return state;
 }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include your action code.

Comment: I've just edited it

Comment: Your reducer does not append the currency to any currency array, it just returns the fetched currency as the entire state. I don't think that is what you intended.